# .htaccess rewrite rule code does not work in cpanel hosting

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-hosting

Recently, I just completed part of my website and decided to try and test several things in the live server. Since all the HTML, CSS, and jQuery code worked, I decided to add a couple lines of .htaccess code to remove the file extension when the URL is generated. I am aware on how to do this and have tried many variations of the code, but the results are either a "500 Internal Error" or the URL does not get rewritten.

This is the code that I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCOnd %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've replaced the "domain" part of the code into my own domain name. But the URL still stays the same (it still includes the ".html" file extension). I am trying to change the URL "www.mydomain.com/folder/file.html" into "www.mydomain.com/folder/file".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:
I've managed to make the file extensions disappear through this code:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\/(.*)\.html$ http://example.com/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

However, I found that it redirects me to a 404 error page. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the mod-rewrite or htaccess is enabled on your server?

Comment: I have tried to find a way to access the httpd.conf file, but for some reason I could not find it. I am using cPanel without WHM, where could I find that file?